# How to access the function's arguments through a function call

Tags: javascript, function, loops, parameters

This program is supposed to stop for 3 sec, log 3000ms have passed, pause for 2, log 2000 ms have passed, etc.

The objective is to write the `callOneByOne` function only. Is there a way to access the arguments in the `call`s array. For example `printCall(3000)` -> I want to access the '3000' as a number or string inside the `callOneByOne` function. Is it possible? If not, how to solve it?

```js
'use strict';

function printCall(waitingTime) {

  return function(callback) {

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`${waitingTime}ms have passed`);
      if (callback) {
        callback();
      }
    }, waitingTime);

  }

}

function callOneByOne($$, $) {
  //Enter Code Here
}

let calls = [printCall(3000), printCall(2000), printCall(4000)];

(calls.reduce((__, _) => callOneByOne(__, _), _ => _()))();
```